# SQL Developer - cannot see some of the rows at the end?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I know that I have about 180 rows in my table. But, SQL developer lets me scroll down and see only 100. The scroll tab/field shows that there are more than 100. But, when i pull the scroll bar down, i don't see the remaining rows. After that, when i release the mouse button, the scroll bar returns to the middle of the scroll field.

This never happened before. Could it be a bug ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on any field of the rows that were returned, then hit CTRL+END to retrieve the reset of the rows... that is how I have always done it.

EDIT: could also be your preferences 
Tools -> Preferences 
Expand Database 
click on Advanced
update the SQL Array Fetch Value (MAX = 500)

Comment: Wow ! What just happened ? CTRL + END solves the problem but mouse scroll does not. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Could be a bug... I am using 3.0.04

Comment: Silly question what happens when you re-drag your shrunken scroll bar, do you get more rows?

Comment: I am not sure what that means. After ctrl+end, i see all rows. I can also move my scroll bar normally. But, if i press the refresh button and move the bar, same problem occurs.

Comment: Really helpful, 500 LIMIT was a bugbear of mine, didn't realize you could get all the records so easily...

Comment: Ctrl+end helped me to see all the remaining rows